# How do we find more appropriate constants for expansions of functions?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

We all knonw that the expansion of  $e^x$ is $$1+x+x^2/2+...$$.
But what if I want to find more approximate expansion of $e^x$. I try that
$$e^x-1-c_0(x)+(c_0+c_1)(x^2/2)-(c_0+c_1+c_2)(x^3/3)=0$$ and substituting the values $x=1,2,3$ to get these constants. And I get more approximate results by solving 3 equations. Is there any way to find more appropriate constants for this function.Which values of $x$ must be taken to get less error?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: The series expansion you are using is the Taylor series centered at 0, notice that no matter what values of constants you use, the error will be exactly 0.

Comment: Look at Lagrange-interpolation, Hermite-interpolation, Pade approximation

Answer (score 2):

The usual power series
fits a function at a point
(often zero)
and gets worse
the further you get
from that point.

To get an approximation
that is good over a 
whole interval,
look at Chebychev approximations
or least squares fitting.

Comment: Let me ask it in this way. When we substitute x=1 into $$1 + x + x^2/2 + x^3/6 + x^4/24$$ we get $$2.70833$$. But when we substitute x=1 into $$1.0000142+ 1.0000142717x + 0.497828x^2 + 0.17261x^3 + 0.043153755 x^4$$ I get $$2.71363$$ which is more close to $$e^1=2.718..$$. I find the 2. function by entering these commands into mathematica $$f[x_] = e^x - B x^2 - C ( (x^3)/6 + x^4/24) - A (1 + x)$$,$$Solve[{f[0.1] == 0, f[0.4] == 0, f[0.6] == 0}, {A, B, C}]$$,$$g[A_, B_, C_] = -(-B x^2 - C ( (x^3)/6 + x^4/24) - A (1 + x))$$ and so on. Is thre any way to choose suitable vls  0.1,0.4 and 0.6 ?

Comment: Can we choose more appropriate values instead of 0.1,0.4 and 0.6 to get more accurate solution?

Comment: Least squares fit: Minimize $\int_a^b (f(x)-p_n(x))^2 dx$, where $p_n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.

Answer (score 1):

you are approximating a function using polynomial. If this is a not homework question, you should find a textbook on approximation using spline function since what you have done is close to B-spline.

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series around a certain point $x_0$ is already an *exact* expansion. Usually what you use is the McLaurin series, which is the taylor series for $x_0 = 0$. Thence you cannot fine a "more approximate" expansion of $e^x$. What you can do is to write down the *general* expansion of $e^x$ for a point $x_0 \neq 0$, which would read:

$$e^x = e^{x_0}\left(1 + (x - x_0) + \frac{1}{2}(x - x_0)^2 + \frac{1}{3!}(x - x_0)^3 + \cdots\right) = e^{x_0} \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(x - x_0)^k}{k!}$$

The coefficients $1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{6}, \cdots $ arise naturally by the definition of Taylor Series itself, and they will be different for different functions.